# extends class but can not access the function of the subclass

Tags: javascript

Below are my javascript code

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {

    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}
function BController (){
} 
function AController (){
    BController.call(this);
} 

AController.prototype.dosomething=function(){
}
```

if I call

```
 var g=new AController();
 g.dosomething ();
```

everything is fine. But if I call (I hope AContronller inherits BController)

```
 extend(AController,BController);
 var g=new AController();
 g.dosomething ();
```

it always reports

```
g.dosomething is not a function
```

**Method 2:**
if I change Acontroller as

```
function AController ( ){
   this.dosomethingNew=function(){

   }
}
```

and call

```
 extend(AController,BController);
 var g=new AController();
 g.dosomethingNew ();
```

it will be fine.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the call to extend in the wrong place.  At the time extend is called, you're overwriting the entire prototype of AController, and losing `dosomething` in the process.

Instead, you want to call extend *before* you add all of the things specific to AController.

So it should look like this:

```
function BController ( ){  
} // <--- no semicolon after function declarations

function AController (){
   BController.call(this);
} // <---- remove here too

extend(AController, BController);  //  <---- HERE
//Now AController's prototype is a new object whose prototype 
//is BController's prototype, thereby inheriting everything from 
//BController.  Now you may add specific stuff to AController 

AController.prototype.dosomething = function(){

};
```

Here's a **[functioning demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdKp5/)**

Comment: I like to put the things concern a class to one place, just likes method 2 (I have updated the question), but it will occupy more memory than the way prototype, is it right?

Comment: @arachide Try this, it will not waste any  memory http://jsfiddle.net/SPXwZ/ and has everything about a class in one place :P

Comment: I changed Acontroller to

Comment: var AController = (function() {
 
    var p = AController.prototype;

    function AController() {

    }
    
    p.dosomething = function() {
    
    };

    return AController;
})();

Comment: it still reports 'g.dosomething is not a function'

Comment: only call: var g=new AController();

  g.dosomething(); it will report 'g.dosomething is not a function'

Comment: @arachide - I put in a link to a functioning fiddle that seems to be what you want.

Comment: I have to consider the memory, what I did is develop a mobile game using javascript

Comment: @arachide - indeed - so putthing these methods on the prototype is probably your best bet.  So be careful *where* you're calling extend, so that you don't wipe out other functions you previously added.

Comment: Inheritance By John Resig is another option:http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ but I do not like very much

Comment: @arachide you have seriously misunderstood. Using closures does not mean you waste memory. The reason defining functions in a constructor wastes memory is because you define functions in a constructor, not because of any closure. You can even define non-closures in a constructor and the memory waste will be the same. Sigh. Defining functions in a constructor is the problem, not closures. Functions have observable identity and are for example in V8 extremely fat objects, that's why it takes a lot of memory to hold tons of wasted fat identities around that point to same code.